# How to check in javascript if web page is accessing the microphone already?

Tags: javascript, html, window, media, microphone

I have multiple actions on my web page which start the microphone separately, I need to check if one action already did this then do not allow others to do this.

Edit-

Is there any way in javascript that I can check if the microphone is on or off on the web page?

Answer (score 0):

It's labeled as "experimental", but microphone has been added to the [permissions.query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query) method. You could do `navigator.permissions.query({name:"microphone"}).then(function(permissionStatus) {...})`

The [permissionStatus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PermissionStatus) will be either "granted", "declined", or "prompt".

Comment: But this is to check that what permissions are given to the microphone, how can I check that microphone is on or off?

Comment: @NehaSoni So you don't want to check if the webpage is "accessing the microphone", you want to check if the microphone is on or off?